# Bind to touched-property of an AbstractControl

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 6 and I've got a component that takes a ControlContainer in the constructor to get a form control later by name. Then I listen to the statusChanges-Observable of the form control:

`constructor(private ngxErrorsService: NgxErrorsService,
              private control: ControlContainer,
              private vcr: ViewContainerRef) { }
...
this._ngxErrors = this.control.control.get(value);
this._ngxErrors.statusChanges.subscribe( o => this.update() );`

So far, so good. But I also need to listen to a change of the touched-property of the form control. Because there is no event in AbstractControl, I thought about binding to the touched-property, but I don't know how to do this dynamically at runtime. Or is there another way I can achieve the same?

Comment: which type of form are you using template driven or reactive form?

Comment: it's a reactive form